# How to get files from ressources folder to copy them in an other directory in C#?

Tags: c#, copy, directory

Hello I would like to know if it was possible to extract the files from the ressources folder to copy thme in a directory at the moment i've tried this :

```
    protected void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            info.CopyTo(PATH + "\\shell" + "\\" + file, true);
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(file);
            Image bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile(Environment.GetFolderPath   (Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "ConnectableCORR\\ApplicationConnectTable\\Resources\\teapot.jpg");
            bitmap.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(PATH + "\\shell" + "\\" + "thumbnail_3D.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
     }
```

But the copy isn't working am I  doing anything wrong?

Best regards.

Comment: As you can see the CopyTo i'm making doesn't works I'll try save.

Comment: "CopyTo" generates an exception if the source file does not exist or the destination is wrong, you can see in my reply.

Comment: Please start writing cleaner code. Combine path and filename using `Path.Combine()` to avoid duplicate backslashes. Which directory is your resource directory? Are you sure you're not confusing that folder with embedded resources (because you also use a ResourceManager)? Why pass a directory name as argument which expects a filename? Give us some hints on the types of variables used (`file` and `PATH`).

Answer (score 0):

The method "[Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)" of object "Image" requires the name of file in "filename", and you are sending it:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(PATH + "\\ shell" + "\\" + "thumbnail_3D.png")
```

[Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Would return:

```
PATH + "\\ shell" + "\\"
```

Would fail the file name, you should also include the file name.

**Edit**

Try this and check the paths:

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File '{0}' exist '{1}'", info.FullName, info.Exists));

var destinationFile = string.Format("{0}\\shell\\{1}", PATH, file);
info.CopyTo(destinationFile, true);

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File '{0}' exist '{1}'", destinationFile, File.Exists(destinationFile)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to focus on the `info.CopyTo()` call, as that is the better way of your two options to copy the file. As it is written, there are a number of possibilities as to why it isn't working. For everything I'm thinking about, an exception would be thrown, so you should be able to add a `try-catch` block around your code and debug to see what the error is. Here's my best guesses, in the order I would try to debug them:

1. What is `file`? Is it a filename? Is it a full path plus filename? It looks to me like your code expects it to be fully-qualified in one place and just the name in another.
2. Source file doesn't exist. I would do a quick `info.Exists` to confirm that the file exists before trying to copy it.
3. Make sure the output filename makes sense. If `file` includes a path, then you really probably want to do `info.CopyTo(PATH + "\\shell\\" + info.Name, true)` unless you want to include the source path in the output path.
4. Output directory doesn't exist. If this is the case. A `DirectoryNotFoundException` will be thrown. Check if the directory exists and create it before doing your `CopyTo`.
5. Bad file name. Might contain invalid characters, which will cause either an `ArgumentException` or a `NotSupportedException`.
6. Path too long. Probably not this, but a `PathTooLongException` would be thrown.